# Pass a parameter by reference in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I am writing a `proto` file for implementing a `gRPC` service and its contract needs to be the same as one of my existing `WCF` services. The `WCF` service has an operation contract that is defined as below:

```
 [OperationContract]
 public ResponseObject Calculate(string value, ref List<string> warnings)
```

I am trying to do the same implementation in `protobuf`. This is what I have as the `rpc` and message:

```
rpc Calculate(RequestMessage) returns (ResponseObject)

message RequestMessage{
    string value = 1;
    repeated string warnings = 2;
    //there is no equivalent to pass by reference types 'ref'
}
```

As you can see above, I know that we can use the repeated type in `protobuf` to represent a List, but is there a supported way to use a pass by reference to a type? In the above operation, I have to do calculations and update the referenced list directly. Is there a way to do something similar in `protobuf`? I tried to go through the documents but did not find a way to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a ref parameter for a List. You could add, remove and work with the list content without having it as a ref parameter. (unless you need to set a new object for the parameter, there is no need for it)

Comment: in the existing WCF implementation, a new object is also set in some conditions. it seems a necessity as of now and is legacy code. I am trying to work around it. wondering if protobuf allows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No-yes.

You can't share machine memory references using protocol buffers.

Protocol buffers define abstract types that can be implemented across language (runtimes) and machine types and often (not always) between multiple processes running on different machines. For these reasons, sharing memory (!) references would be difficult and possibly meaningless.

You can however use identifiers to represent instances of types. When a peer creates types, each can be referenced to other peers using some unique identifier. Peers must then either maintain list of these references or be able to look them up but identifiers can then be shipped across e.g. a network to a remote peer in the guise of a list of references; portable unique identifiers rather than machine-specific memory references.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll take a look into this!

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck